# Possible to call external program in Forth?

Tags: forth

I'm experimenting with Forth (.4th file extension) through FICL. Is it possible to call the execution of an external program - like my "Hello, World!" assembly executable - from inside a .4th source file?

Answer (score 3):

Look for words like `system` or `sh`.  I understand you are using FICL and the ANS94 standard does not require such words to be available, but check your local documentation to see if any extended words have been added for shelling out to the system.

For example, in Gforth, you have the `system` word. Here is how you would run the `hello` executable in the current working directory:

```
s" ./hello" system
```

More information (Gforth, specific): ["passing commands to the operating system"](https://gforth.org/manual/Passing-Commands-to-the-OS.html).  FICL is extendable.  ;-)  Good luck.